# How does C uppercase letters?

Tags: c, glibc

I see this code [in `glibc-2.33/ctype/ctype.c`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=ctype/ctype.c;h=8c899336d8ca8ef972be2b8d6be99c147eea78d8;hb=HEAD):

```c
// [...]

#define __ctype_toupper \
  ((int32_t *) _NL_CURRENT (LC_CTYPE, _NL_CTYPE_TOUPPER) + 128)

// [...]

int
toupper (int c)
{
  return c >= -128 && c < 256 ? __ctype_toupper[c] : c;
}
libc_hidden_def (toupper)
```

I understand that it's checking if `c` is within -128 and 256 (inclusive) and returns the character as-is if it's outside that range, but what does `_NL_CURRENT (LC_CTYPE, _NL_CTYPE_TOUPPER) + 128)` mean and where do I actually find the source code of how letters are uppercased? This seems to be looking up the current locale, I am only interested in `en_US.UTF-8`. Also, how can a character be negative?

I don't care about `glibc` specifically, I just want to know how all the ASCII characters (all as in from NUL to DEL) are uppercased in C.

Comment: Note: C only defined `toupper(int ch)` in the `unsigned char` range and `EOF`.

Comment: It's implementation-specific.  Commonly it's a lookup table (an array with an entry for every character), but how that array is loaded for the appropriate locale can be complicated.

Comment: When the _locale_ is not _C_, the characters [0..127]  are not certainly _ASCII_ anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"C" doesn't convert characters to upper case. The C standard only mandates that there be a function in the standard library which does so correctly according to the current locale, and that it does so in a particular way in the "C" locale (which is the only locale which is guaranteed to exist).

Library implementations are free to accomplish that task as the implementers see fit, and they all do it in different ways. Even radically different ways. Some C libraries don't support locales other than the "C" locale with an ASCII character set. An example of such a C library is [musl](https://musl.libc.org/about.html) and it is hard to beat the simplicity of its implementation:

```c
int toupper(int c)
{
        if (islower(c)) return c & 0x5f;
        return c;
}
```

As you can see, the above code depends on `islower`. Here it is:

```c
int islower(int c)
{
        return (unsigned)c-'a' < 26;
}
```

Because of the call to `islower`, `toupper` returns unchanged any argument outside of the range of lower case characters, even arguments not in the valid range for toupper. Since the standard doesn't define the behaviour of `toupper` for arguments outside of the valid range (essentially values which might be returned by `fgetc`), just returning invalid arguments unchanged is certainly as acceptable as any other behaviour. Glibc's `toupper` function will often segfault on invalid arguments, since it uses the argument as an index into an array (as you can see in the code you cite). That behaviour is also acceptable according to the standard.

The Glibc implementation is a lot more complicated. And behind the scenes it depends on the locale data which is compiled from locale definition files, a process which is completely outside of the C standard and somewhat defined by the Posix standard (although the GNU implementation diverges in some way from Posix).

But here's the scoop: If you're using single byte characters in a UTF-8 locale, none of glibc's complicated code makes the slightest difference. The musl implementation works precisely as required in a UTF-8 locale, because the only alphabetic characters representable in a single byte UTF-8 representation are the 52 characters in the "Roman" alphabet. All the other Unicode characters are only representable in wide characters and multibyte sequences.

Furthermore, environments which use a single-byte encoding other than UTF-8 are increasingly rare. There are certainly a lot of us who had to learn this stuff because our programs ran on a variety of platforms which used different [ISO-8859-x code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859). Or different single-byte Windows codepages. But in the end, Unicode won out. (And many of us breathed huge sighs of relief.) So most of this apparatus is no longer really necessary except in legacy environments.

But that's not to say that Unicode magically solves all the complications involved in managing the huge variety of alphabets in use in the world. Far from it. What Unicode does do is two-fold: it clarifies what the complications are (most of which is not captured by C/Posix locales), and it provides some basic standards for implementations.

And, as a side effect, UTF-8 standardises single-byte codes to basically conform with the original ASCII 7-bit standard. So if you're only dealing with 7-bit characters (which, these days, is probably less than ideal), you don't need anything beyond musl-style implementations. And if you are dealing with "all the world's character sets", you'll be looking for a library which actually conforms to Unicode, and which uses something other than `char` to represent characters.

But one complication is going to remain forever, sadly: the fact that C does not standardise the signedness of `char`. On platforms on which `char` is signed (Unix X86 and Windows, for two major examples),
`(char)0xA0` is (a) unspecified and (b) probably -96, which is what a single-byte 0xA0 represents in 2's complement. So if you write code which uses the various functions in `ctype.h` and don't take care of negative `char` values, and then you try to use that code with a UTF-8 encoded string which includes characters outside of the single-byte domain, then you will end up passing negative numbers to functions which might not be expecting them.

Comment: I'm [reimplementing](https://github.com/yargs/yargs-parser/pull/366) bash's parsing of [ANSI-C quoted strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) in JavaScript and I'm trying to figure out why `echo -n '^?' | xxd -b` (ctrl-v + backspace) shows `01111111` but `echo -n $'\c^?' | xxd -b` shows `00000001 01111111` and not `00011111`. `TOCTRL` is [defined](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/include/chartypes.h) as `((x) == '?' ? 0x7f : (TOUPPER(x) & 0x1f))` and is used [here](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/sh/strtrans.c)

Comment: @Boris: you might have gotten a more useful answer if you had asked the question which really interested you :-)

Comment: Here's the part of the answer to what I believe is your real question, condensed to fit in a comment: See the comment at the top of `strtrans.c` which says "If (FLAGS&2) is non-zero, we're expanding for the parser and want to quote CTLESC and CTLNUL with CTLESC." The symbols referred to in that comment are defined in `syntax.h` as `\001` and `\177` respectively. You're seeing the result (a CTLCUL quoted with CTLESC). Some would call that a bug. But, then, `\c<bksp>` is not really a valid escape sequence.

Comment: @Boris: Anyway, you gave me an opportunity to vent my locale rant somewhat legitimately. So I'm not complaining. If you ask your real question, I'll try to answer it.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed answer! I asked my real question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66982114/how-does-bash-parse-control-character-escape-codes-in-ansi-c-quoted-strings (but you've already answered it)

Answer (score 0):

If you go back at the root and look for `_NL_CTYPE_TOUPPER` you will find a commit where it is written

> [..] (ctype_output): Support for alternate locale format: Computation of
> nelems changes. _NL_CTYPE_TOUPPER32 [...]

So basically _NL_CTYPE_TOUPPER is the macro for _NL_CTYPE_TOUPPER(8bits) as for example in French you have `À` as uppercase version of `à`

Following this link you will find the header file [langinfo.h](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=locale/langinfo.h;h=0062cda90812f7afee25651f69a9aa094717afef;hb=ef4461440540e0ad4e25ba35203594e25dc38b3a) that has this enum starting at line 43 and with `_NL_CTYPE_TOUPPER` defined at line 259.

> LC_CTYPE category: character classification.
> 256      This information is accessed by the functions in <ctype.h>.

LC_CTYPE is defined for each language, see for example for [French](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=localedata/locales/fr_FR;hb=ef4461440540e0ad4e25ba35203594e25dc38b3a):

> fr_FR:2000"

Note that it doesn't make a lot of sense to call this function since characters with accent are not contained in the ASCII table, but since this function is the one handling both utf8 and ascii that's how it works.

Comment: ctype.h functions are expected to handle locale. Which is not necessarily UTF8, back in the days when this header was designed, there was no standard. At best you could assume 7 bit ASCII.