# How does bash parse control character escape codes in ANSI-C quoted strings?

Tags: c, bash, glibc

I'm re-implementing bash's [ANSI-C quoted strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) in JavaScript but I am having trouble understanding how control characters in them are parsed. I see the code in [`lib/sh/strtrans.c`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/sh/strtrans.c) does this:

```c
            case 'c':
              if (sawc)
                {
                  *sawc = 1;
                  *r = '\0';
                  if (rlen)
                    *rlen = r - ret;
                  return ret;
                }
              else if ((flags & 1) == 0 && *s == 0)
                ;               /* pass \c through */
              else if ((flags & 1) == 0 && (c = *s))
                {
                  s++;
                  if ((flags & 2) && c == '\\' && c == *s)
                    s++;        /* Posix requires $'\c\\' do backslash escaping */
                  c = TOCTRL(c);
                  break;
                }
```

and `TOCTRL` is defined in [`include/chartypes.h`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/include/chartypes.h) as

```c
#  define TOCTRL(x) ((x) == '?' ? 0x7f : (TOUPPER(x) & 0x1f))
```

where `TOUPPER` is effectively C's `toupper` function.

So what I would expect is it takes at the first byte of the character after "`\c`", uppercases it if it's a letter, and zero's out the first three bits of the result.

Exhaustively testing this with a NodeJS script, I found that this rule doesn't work for two cases:

```sh
$ bash -c $'echo -n "\x01" | xxd -b'
00000000: 00000001                                               .
$ bash -c $'echo -n $\'\\c\x01\' | xxd -b'
00000000: 00000001 00000001                                      ..

$ bash -c $'echo -n "\x7F" | xxd -b'
00000000: 01111111                                               .
$ bash -c $'echo -n $\'\\c\x7F\' | xxd -b'
00000000: 00000001 01111111                                      ..
```

(apologies if that's confusing, I am using an ANSI-C quoted string to generate a bash command with another ANSI-C quoted string inside so that I can insert arbitrary characters after the `\c`)

and if zeroing out the first 3 bits produces a `00000000` character (e.g. `\c`  (`00100000`) or `\c@` (`01000000`)), that's the NULL, which terminates the string and causes `xxd` to not print anything, but that's not too surprising.

I'm wondering why that happens.

Answer (score 1):

We also need [syntax.h](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/f3a35a2d601a55f337f8ca02a541f8c033682247/syntax.h#L99):

```
#define CTLESC '\001'
#define CTLNUL '\177'
```

And there below in [strtrans.c](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/f3a35a2d601a55f337f8ca02a541f8c033682247/lib/sh/strtrans.c#L216) there is:

```
    case 'c':
      if (sawc)
    {
      *sawc = 1;
      *r = '\0';
      if (rlen)
        *rlen = r - ret;
      return ret;
    }
      else if ((flags & 1) == 0 && *s == 0)
    ;       /* pass \c through */
      else if ((flags & 1) == 0 && (c = *s))
    {
      s++;
      if ((flags & 2) && c == '\\' && c == *s)
        s++;    /* Posix requires $'\c\\' do backslash escaping */
      c = TOCTRL(c);
      break;
    }
    /*FALLTHROUGH*/
    default:
    if ((flags & 4) == 0)
      *r++ = '\\';
    break;
    }
  # c is 0x01 or 0x1f
  if ((flags & 2) && (c == CTLESC || c == CTLNUL))
    *r++ = CTLESC;     # adds 0x01
  *r++ = c;            # adds 0x01 or 0x1f
}
```

I do not know where the `\c` escape sequence does come from. It's [not in C](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4) and tbh I did not see it used, as far as I can tell. Where does it come from? I wanted to say that using `\c$'\x01'` and `\c$'\x1f'` would count as "undefined behavior", but I have no idea which characters are actually allowed anyway.

And I like `xxd -p` more then `xxd -b` :p