# Convert a spanish string to uppercase

Tags: c

I want to convert a Spanish string to uppercase.  I use the function `toupper` for all characters.  The function does not convert characters with accent:

> PROTECCIóN

Nor the enye character:

> DAñO

I use the setlocale function.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66978556/how-does-c-uppercase-letters is related.

Comment: What platform do you compile for? The encoding seems to be missing from the locale specifier.

Comment: Some platforms (such as Linux) use two bytes for characters above 127. If you store the text in a `char[]` array, the `ó` is stored in two characters; passing each of both to `toupper()` will get you nowhere.

Comment: Could you print the decimal (or hexadecimal) value of each character in the stored string? That would help diagnose any mismatch between the character set of the "es_ES" locale and the actual character set of the stored string.

Comment: @MartinRosenau I think the C language (as opposed to newer languages like Java and C#) always uses one-byte characters in C strings, including string literals (`"PROTECCIóN"`). That is independent of the operating system, right?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica This has nothing to do with C but with the terminal (such as Linux "gnome-terminal"): The OS converts characters like "ó" to two or three characters ("Ã³" in the case of "ó"). So a `getchar()` will receive two characters if you type "ó" on the keyboard. The output is processed the other way round: If the program performs a `puts("Ã³")`, the screen will display "ó". If you type "protección" on the keyboard, `gets()` will actually receive "protecciÃ³n". "Ã" is already uppercase and "³" is not a letter.

Comment: @Martin Well, the C language is concerned with the byte representation of the string "ó"  in a C array. What you just described seems to indicate that the array indeed contains only 1 character (243) plus the terminating 0. It's the input and output by the OS/terminal that reads resp. writes two character sequences. And since `toupper('ó')` does not involve I/O the function should see one byte, 243 (in the Latin or Windows encoding).

Comment: @MartinRosenau Interesting. On godbolt the string is stored as 2 bytes + 0 (https://www.godbolt.org/z/oMsYov9rj).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get the good result with `setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES.utf8");`, and use of `wchar_t` and of `towupper(.)` function.

**Output**

```
protección daño  PROTECCIÓN DAÑO
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void) {
    if (!setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES.utf8")) return 1;
    wchar_t input[] = L"protección daño";
    int length = sizeof(input)/sizeof(input[0]);
    wchar_t output[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length-1; ++i) {
        output[i] = towupper(input[i]);
    }
    output[length-1] = '\0';
    printf ("%ls  %ls\n", input, output);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In addition one might also check if `setlocal` returns `NULL`,  indicating that the language is e.g. not installed on the system

Comment: @Odysseus Effectively. Not needed in a short test programme, but better in a serious one. Added. Thanks.